# how to using jquery .animate for clip : rect

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

i try to using this

```
var a ='1200';
var b= '400';
var current_slide = $('.swiper-slide-active');
var current_twenty = current_slide.find('.twentytwenty-wrapper');
var current_twentyCont = current_twenty.find('.twentytwenty-container');
var current_twentyContBefore = current_twentyCont.find('img.twentytwenty-before');

current_twentyContBefore.animate({ clip: "rect(0px,"+a+"px,"+b+"px, 0px)"; }, 1000 );
```

but it doesnt work. I try to not using jquery animate fx.step

any way to solve the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try like below

```
current_twentyContBefore.animate({
  fontSize: 100 //some unimportant CSS to animate so we get some values
},
{
  step: function(now, fx) { //now is the animated value from initial css value
      $(this).css('clip', 'rect(0px, '+now+'px, '+now+'px, 0px)')
  }
}, 1
```

Comment: in my case i have different value sir. i cant use `now` for different value